# Not Admin | Firmware password error | Recovery Mode wont boot

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, disk-utility, external-disk, firmware-password

This probably sounds pretty sketchy, so I’ll preface my question with a brief run down of how I got here...

Pretty sure I was hacked... It’s a mid-2012 running High Sierra on a SSD harrdrive.

Bought it used last year from a vintage Mac dealer, who gave it to me loaded with programs I needed (should have had him wipe it clean).

But anyway, when I was hacked .. the firmware lock initiated,  admin password changed. I have the password to the firmware but (like a moron), I didn’t write it carefully enough and there are about 4 characters that could go either way ...

“Is that a 2? Or a z?”

After about 4 hours of mindlessly popping in different variables, I finally cracked it, but don’t know exactly what I entered. I got access to the login and reset the user password.

After getting hacked, all I’ve wanted to do is wipe the drive clean... 
I took it to a guy I know and he didn’t have time to fix but had a hard drive ready to go. Unfortunately, got home and booted up to another firmware lock — with no login access.

I brought it back, and he used some device on the firmware — wasn’t able to reset the firmware password - couldn’t boot in recovery mode -  but was able to make it so I could login as a user (with plans to fix bios chip next week).

Since I do a lot of work on the computer, need it to work now, and need it to be secure.

So, I made some adjustments to override other users (thinking the user name I was given (“Admin”) was the administrator user.

Not realizing ... I am just a “standard user”, I restricted permissions of “standard users” and reset login access..

Now, not only can I not boot in restore mode, single user mode,..etc.. . I can’t unlock padlocks or authorize downloads, change user settings, change file permissions..

It prompts me with a Blank login (user name and password). I write in what I use to login and it doesn’t work.

Can’t change network settings, boot disk utility drives...

Can’t recovery boot... Can’t update my anti-virus and firewall...

So finally, here’s my question:

Is there a way to.... use terminal to mount a bootable installer partition of an external, and and restore with OS running — instead of ion start up?

Or, use terminal while in standard user mode to upgrade permissions in the root folder,

Or, use terminal to reveal admin name and password?

Reset the password? Switch to single user mode without restarting? Anything?

any ideas you have are much appreciated!

And thanks !!

Comment: I think you're going to have to try to recover/guess the firmware password again, and this time write down what variant actually worked.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks—not necessarily a huge math guy—but wondering if you might have some sort of simple variable formula that can make the process more methodical?

Comment: If there are only 4 characters that "could go either way", and only two possibilities for each, there are only 16 overall possibilities. What I'd do is take your best guess for each of the characters, and try that. Then try the other possibility for the last one. Then try the other possibility for the next-to-last one, repeating it with both possibilities for the last one. (For instance, if the last two were 2-or-Z and 1-or-L and you think 2L is most likely, try ...2L, ...21, ...ZL, ...Z1). Then try the other character for the third-from last character, and repeat those 4.

Comment: For example, if the third-from-last character was 3-or-E, and you'd already tried 3, you'd try ...E2L, ...E21, ...EZL, ...EZ1. If that doesn't do it, repeat that entire thing but with the other option for the first questionable character.